# JAVA How to append the return value of .map() in a list instead of returning a list of list

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a java code something like

```
/*Statement A*/
dataList.stream.map(ClassA::mapFunction).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

The catch is mapFunction has the following definition:

```
List<Entry> mapFunction(DataListItem dataListItem)
```

therefore the above stream().map() call returns `List<List<Entry>>`

What I want is that the return value should be `list<Entry>` (basically appending all the return values) and for that what I am currently doing is:

```
final List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList<>();
dataList.stream.map(dataListItem -> entryList.addAll(ClassA.mapFunction(dataListItem))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a clean way to append the mapFunction return values such that the outcome of Statement A is just a `List<Entry>` instead of `List<List<Entry>>`.

Comment: like this using flatmap `dataList.stream.map(ClassA::mapFunction).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flatMap` operation, which is a thing you do to streams same as `map`, `filter`, `collect`, etc, and it does the following:

You supply a lambda that turns each element in the stream into a stream itself (so a stream of streams), and then the 'output' of the operation is a single stream consisting of all these streams concatenated together.